# main url redirect

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect

is it possible to have the main domain of a wordpress blog(example.com) to redirect to another site and the actual posts and pages (example.com/post1, example.com/about, etc') to not be redirected and instead reside on the wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action('init', 'redirect_home');
function redirect_home() {
  if( is_home() ) {
    wp_redirect('http://example.com');
  }
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: functions.php for your active theme.

Comment: it didn't work for me usin the wordpress Classic theme(grey//white colors). Does t work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ http://other.example.com/ [L,R]
```

This example is for the .htaccess file in the document root directory and will redirect requests to *other.example.com*.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at using the WordPress redirection function in place of the header location..

```
wp_redirect('someurl', 301);
```

301 is the status code to use, and of course someurl is where you'd place your URL to reirect to.. (301 is default, so not required unless you want a difference status code)